# wp_tag_cloud: list only general tags associated with a custom taxonomy tag

Tags: tags, conditional-tags

I have a custom taxonomy called, for example, "colour". And I have normal tags. I use them both on posts.

So, for a specific tag cloud I'm building, I want it to list all taxonomies that are associated with tag "large", for example. This tag cloud will be in an unrelated page. Is that possible?

Example:

- Post 1
  ---- Taxonomy: Black
  ---- Tag: Large
- Post 2
  ---- Taxonomy: White
  ---- Tag: Large
- Post 3
  ---- Taxonomy: White
  ---- Tag: Small
- Post 4
  ---- Taxonomy: Red
  ---- Tag: Medium
- Unrelated Page
  ---- Tag cloud output: Black, White

Comment: Yes this is possible. You can get the `object_id` from the table wp_term_relationships for the color white. Then you have all the posts that are tagged white. For each of these object id’s you can find all the tags added to them in this same table.

Comment: I got confused and asked for the tag when I wanted to list the taxonomies. Post edited to become more clear.

Comment: I managed to get this query to work (see pastebin link bellow), but I'm having trouble figuring out how to transcribe it to wp_tag_cloud.

The idea of the sql were to first list all posts that have that specific tag (term_taxonomy_id=102). Then I got all the object_id from these posts and listed the terms for the desired taxonomy (term slug = taxonomy-slug).

https://pastebin.com/7gFiRtzB